# How to check if a site runs on magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

Is there any way to check if a given website runs on Magento? Looking for a programmatic way. I have tried to look in the documentation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 9):

You can check from websites like http://www.builtwith.com/.

There are many browser extensions also available to check website's technology.

If you want to check by manual debugging, there are many ways to find whether a site is running on Magento or not.

- Check page source of any page, if it has like skin/frontend
- In address bar, open url /downloader, if it opens magento connect login page.
- In address bar, open url /install.php, if site is Magento site, then it will show following error:

  FAILED ERROR: Magento is already installed
- Another clue can be admin url. Most of Magento stores don't bother to change admin url. If it opens by hitting /index.php/admin and shows Magento somewhere on page, then it is 100% running on Magento Platform.
- Magento/Varien can be found in page source if a website is built with magento.

**Note:** All these manual instructions are for magento version < 2.0

I hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

By using the page view source, it can be easily identified whether site is running on Magento or not with a more specific version.

**Magento 2: Mage cookies script tag will be as follows:**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "mage/cookies": {
            "expires": null,
            "path": "/",
            "domain": ".www.example.com",
            "secure": false,
            "lifetime": "3600"
        }
    }
}
```

**Magento 1: Mage cookies script tag will be as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.example.com';
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Note that not all pages on a site might have this. For example `/store` might, but `/home` might not have any reference to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that an easy way of checking this exists, but there are some browser extensions that can do the job for you.

For example, to Google Chrome you can use [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae).

From the description:

> Detect web applications and javascript libraries run on browsing
>   website. This extension will help web developer to inspect web
>   framework / CMS and javascript library running on current browsing
>   website. An icon will appear on address bar indicates the detected
>   framework. Version detecting is being implemented.
>
> Currently, this extension can detect more than 100 popular CMS and
>   javascript libraries, and more will be added in future releases. Visit
>   extension website for more detail.

Comment: Thank you Diogo! But I was looking for more of a programmatic approach. Are there any places that release the approach they use?

Answer (score 0):

Magento spews this information all over the place, snag any stock javascript in the JS folder and look for Magento/Varien copyright headers.

Magento/Varien copyright headers also spew from the skin folders in CSS and JS files.

Plenty of indicators in routing URLs as well.